# changing chart size in Excel from Python win32com

Tags: python, excel, charts, size, win32com

I'm trying to change the size of a chart in an Excel spreadsheet using win32com and Python. The code below takes an Excel file that is already populated with data, and adds a chart which I would like to resize. Any ideas on code to add\modify to change the size of the chart? Thanks!

```
import win32com.client as win32
xl = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('C:/newfolder/example.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1').Select()
ws = xl.ActiveSheet
ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart().Select()
xl.ActiveChart.ChartType = c.xlXYScatterLines
xl.ActiveChart.SetSourceData(Source = ws.Range(a+':'+b),PlotBy =2)
xl.ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
xl.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = 'Chart of Capabilities'
xl.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
.
.
.
{changing various chart attriutes}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yous should try [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) library

```
import openpyxl
chartwb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = chartwb.get_active_sheet()
referenceobj = openpyxl.charts.Reference(sheet, (1, 1), (10, 1))
serObj = openpyxl.charts.Series(referenceObj, title='Chart Series')
chartObject = openpyxl.charts.BarChart()
chartObject.append(serObj)
chartObject.drawing.top = 50 
chartObject.drawing.left = 100
chartObject.drawing.width = 300 
chartObject.drawing.height = 200
sheet.add_chart(chartObject)
chartwb.save('example.xlsx')
```

Also you can specify the size at the time of creation [expression.AddChart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addchart(v=office.14).aspx)(Type, Left, Top, Width, Height).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [interop docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes_members.aspx), you should be calling `AddChart2` instead of `AddChart`. The former takes arguments for left, top, width, height and returns a [Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shape_members.aspx). If you need to resize the chart later, you should be able to set the `Left` etc on the shape. If you need to retrieve a specific chart, you use the `ChartObjects(index)` property of `Worksheet`, which will get you a [ChartObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.chartobject_members.aspx). It is not clear from the docs what is (if any) relationship between `Shape` and `ChartObject`.